# Проверка на null в JsonDeserializer

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

Есть моделька json

```
{"amount" : null}
```

Необходимо при значении равном `null` возвращать `BigDecimal.ZERO`

Написал десериализатор:

```
class BigDecimalDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> {
    override fun deserialize(json : JsonElement ?, typeOfT : Type ?, context : JsonDeserializationContext ?) : BigDecimal {

        if (json !!.isJsonNull) {
                return BigDecimal.ZERO
        }

        json ?.let {

                try {
                        json.asBigDecimal
                } catch (t : NumberFormatException) {
                        return BigDecimal.ZERO
                }

        }

        return json ?.asBigDecimal !!
    }
}
```

Но ни в одном условии `null` не ловится. Подскажите в чем ошибка.

Comment: Может приведете код десериализации, чтобы поведение можно было бы воспроизвести?

Comment: Попробуйте проверять так `json.asJsonObject.get("amount").isJsonNull`. Ведь ваш корневой объект не null. Он внутри себя содержит объект `amount` который может быть null.

Comment: тут суть в том чтобы не важно было как поле называется

Comment: Для `null`- значений десериализатор вообще не вызывается, а сразу возвращается `null`. Чтобы это обойти, надо назначить кастомный `TypeAdapter<BigDecimal>`, вместо `JsonDeserializer`. Кодом не помогу, так как на котлине не пишу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что GSON смотрит, то это null и ничего не делает. Зачем пытаться десериализировать null? Надо в сорцы глянуть.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что десериализатор не относит ваш json к типу `BigDecimal`, а скорее всего воспринимает его как `String` или что-то другое - соответственно он не попадает в ваш кастомный десериализатор.

Comment: в следствии чего такое может произойти?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю. При десериализации проверяется тип обьекта в который пишем, затем берется подходящий десериализатор и процесс происходит дальше?

Comment: Я же вроде уже разжевал. Десериализатор Gson работает так, берет json определяет его тип, смотрит в списке своих десериализаторов есть у него десериализатор который парсит такой тип если есть отправляет его туда. Теперь догадайтесь с 2-х раз - если есть json строка `{"amount" : null}` - какого типа переменная `amount`? Почему десериализатор должен решить что он `BigDecimal`?

Comment: тогда в чем смысл кастомного десериализатора. Как  в json должен выглядеть BigDecimal???

Comment: @Barmaley как я понял, ОП десериализует в свой класс, в котором есть поле `BigDecimal amount`

Comment: Я бы предположил, что нужен кастомный сериализатор, который складывает в json то что нужно вам, например пихает сразу в json его тип

Comment: Все хуже господа. Есть бэк из которого время от времени сыпятся null-ы. Десериализую в свой обьект. Там тип BigDecimal все верно

Comment: В json складывать соответственно ни чего не надо

Comment: могу тест показать. Там все проходит кроме того что нужно

Comment: Покажите пример json в котором поле `amount` не `null`

Comment: Вот весь тест https://gist.github.com/anonymous/191d8e8e62ef90fbb75cd5d066d27a07

Comment: testIsNullable()  не проходит

Comment: Покажите пример json в котором поле amount не null

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70268/discussion-between-alexmx-and-barmaley).

Answer (score 0):

Интуиция не подвела, GSON точно пропускает null значения.

Из [документации](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#serializeNulls--):

> Configure Gson to serialize null fields. By default, Gson omits all fields that are null during serialization.

Не проверял, но верю что это заставит GSON вызывать ваш `BigDecimalDeserializer`.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

Comment: Это заставит Gson не пропускать поля с null - значениями при сериализации (по умолчанию он их вообще не записывает). Но на десериализацию это не влияет.

Comment: Это я изначально сделал. Тут либо Бармалей прав либо что то не учтено. Я напишу отдельно от проекта все это дело и в дебаге прочекаю как работает.

Comment: Да и тут ньюанс есть все таки. Сам по себе нул оборачивается как JsonNull